# Properties file library for C (or C++)

Tags: c++, c, properties

The title is pretty self-explanatory: does anyone know of a (good) properties file reader library for C or, if not, C++?

Edit: To be specific, I want a library which handles the .properties file format used in Java: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

Comment: Not self explanatory actually - what is a "properties file"?

Comment: Well, I guess that the properties file format - a staple of Java - is not so widely known outside the Java world, which partly explains why I can't find one. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties (I don't have enough reputation to add this to the question.)

Comment: I've added it for you - I hope that I have paraphrased correctly.

Comment: Anyone can edit their own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[STLSoft](http://www.stlsoft.org/)'s [1.10 alpha](https://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=238860&package_id=294944) contains a `platformstl::properties_file` class. It can be used to read from a file:

```
using platformstl::properties_file;

properties_file  properties("stuff.properties");

properties_file::value_type  value = properties["name"];
```

or from memory:

```
properties_file  properties(
    "name0=value1\n name1 value1 \n name\\ 2 : value\\ 2  ",
    properties_file::contents);

properties_file::value_type  value0 = properties["name0"];

properties_file::value_type  value1 = properties["name1"];

properties_file::value_type  value2 = properties["name 2"];
```

Looks like the latest 1.10 release has a bunch of comprehensive unit-tests, and that they've upgraded the class to handle all the rules and examples given in the [Java documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.InputStream)).

The only apparent rub is that the `value_type` is an instance of [`stlsoft::basic_string_view`](http://www.stlsoft.org/doc-1.9/classstlsoft_1_1basic__string__view.html) (described in [this Dr Dobb's article](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184402064)), which is somewhat similar to `std::string`, but doesn't actually own its memory. Presumably they do this to avoid unneccessary allocations, presumably for performance reasons, which is something the STLSoft design holds dear. But it means that you can't just write

```
std::string  value0 = properties["name0"];
```

You can, however, do this:

```
std::string  value0 = properties["name0"].c_str();
```

and this:

```
std::cout << properties["name0"];
```

I'm not sure I agree with this design decision, since how likely is it that reading properties - from file or from memory - is going to need the absolute last cycle. I think they should change it to use `std::string` by default, and then use the "string view" if explicitly required.

Other than that, the `properties_file` class looks like it does the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for. I'll check it out. Your link [4] is broken, btw

Answer (score 5):

libconfuse (C library) is useful, too; it's been around forever & is flexible.

- ( www.nongnu.org/confuse/ ) http://www.nongnu.org/confuse/tutorial-html/index.html

It goes way, way beyond java.util.Properties.  Though, it won't necessarily handle the corner cases of the java properties file format (which seems to be your requirement).

See the examples:

- simple:  www.nongnu.org/confuse/simple.conf
- crazy:  www.nongnu.org/confuse/test.conf

No C++ wrapper library, that I'm aware of, though.

Answer (score 3):

Poco also has an Implementation for Reading PropertyFiles
http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.PropertyFileConfiguration.html

A Simple example copied from here: http://pocoproject.org/slides/180-Configuration.pdf

Property file content:

```
# a comment
! another comment
key1 = value1
key2: 123
key3.longValue = this is a very \
long value
path = c:\\test.dat
```

Code example

```
#include <Poco/Util/PropertyFileConfiguration.h>
using Poco::AutoPtr;
using Poco::Util::PropertyFileConfiguration;
AutoPtr<PropertyFileConfiguration> pConf;
pConf = new PropertyFileConfiguration("test.properties");
std::string key1 = pConf->getString("key1");
int value = pConf->getInt("key2");
std::string longVal = pConf->getString("key3.longValue");
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess by 'properties file' you mean config file.

In this case Google gives (first 4 hits for `C config file library`):

- http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/
- http://rudeserver.com/config/
- http://freshmeat.net/projects/cfl/
- http://liblcfg.carnivore.it/