# NOOB C Programming Question: I'm having trouble with inserting values that are being read from a file into other variables throughout my code

Tags: c, file, readfile

So to simplify my problem, I created this more modular program that asks for user input first in my switch case in my 'main()' and in two other methods as well. I have this code underneath, and in my `readDigits()` method I am wondering how to get specific values from `value` into 'firstDigit and `secondDigit`. Say when `value == 5`, I would want '5' to get into `firstDigit`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int firstDigit, secondDigit, input;

void getNumbers() {
   printf("Enter these digits: \n");
   scanf("%d", &firstDigit);
}

void getMoreNumbers() {
   printf("Enter some more digits: \n");
   scanf("%d", &secondDigit);
}

int readDigits(int value) {
   FILE *fp
   fp = fopen("digits.txt", "r");
   if(fp == NULL) {
     printf("Failed to open file");
     return -1;
   }
   while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &value)==1){
      printf("%d ", value);


**#I was thinking of doing these 'if' checks whenever value has a number that 
#I would want 'firstDigit' ,'secondDigit' , or 'input' to be. But then I 
#figured that this would be too tedious and not efficient If I were to read 
#a file with a lot of data in it.**

      if(value== 1){
         firstDigit = value;
      }
  }   
  fclose(fp);
}  

int main() {
   while(input < 3){
   printf("Please select which method you'd like to access:\n1) getNumbers()\n2getMoreNumbers()");
  // I also want input's value to be read from digits.txt
  scanf("%d", &input);  
  switch(input){
     case 1:
        getNumbers();
        break;
     case 2:
        getMoreNumbers();
        break;
     default:
        printf("Program complete");
     }  
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I understand that this is not nearly the hardest thing ever, however, I am new to C and am really getting stressed out over WHAT I FEEL is a simple problem.

**My file of digits.txt has the values:**

> 1
>   10
>   299
>   1
>   200
>   15
>   3
>   150
>   13
>   2
>   150

Comment: check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874052/properties-file-library-for-c-or-c

Comment: i'd like if it there were solution to this in vanilla c without any libraries

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to set variables? You use `=` for that.

Comment: Don't use same name for parameters and global variables, as first step.

Comment: Posst an example of your input file `""digits.txt""` (or 10 or so lines if it is too long). The will provide a way to measure whether your approach you have shown so far is reasonable.

Comment: Ok I added an example of my digits.txt file  @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: honestly nobody understands what you are trying to do. Your introductory text makes no sense (it refers to readFile, there is no such name in your program). Advice, strip this program down to the very basics and get it working, then build back up. The very basics are, read the file and display its contents. Your first line in main refers to `input` this is not declared at all

Comment: Shoot thank you for the advice. I guess it would've been wise to create this on an IDE first. I'll take keep on trying to make my question readable and understandable

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: lmao i love this community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting your input file. The reason your question has been less than well-received is that it is quite difficult to determine what it is you were trying to achieve. While it is apparent you need help, exactly where to start is a bit of a mystery.

Why? For starters, your `getNumbers()`<sup>[1]</sup> and `getMoreNumbers()` functions do exactly the same thing, simply using a different *global* variable. There is no reason to use *global* variables in any of your functions, as they can be quite easily passed as parameters to any function that needs them. More generally, you want to avoid the use of global variables unless absolutely necessary (there are legitimate uses of globals, but none you are likely to encounter as you are initially learning C -- avoid them)

Next, if you learn nothing else from this answer, learn to **always validate user input** by at minimum checking the return of the function used. Otherwise you are inviting *Undefined Behavior* by blindly using the input variable without any verification that it actually contains valid data.

Stepping back and trying to understand what you are waning to do, it appears your goal is twofold, (1) read an integer from `stdin` based on a menu selection, or (2) read from a file `"digits.txt"` if an alternative menu selection was made. However, your `readDigits()` function is never called. Further, what if you want to read from a file other than `"digits.txt"`? Why not simply prompt the user for a filename and then open that file (handling any error), read all integers from the file, and then close the file when done?

So how do we accomplish those two goals, either reading an integer from `stdin`, or reading all integers from the filename given by the user?

To begin, you have to completely validate all input given by the user and then act on that input handling any error that may arise. `scanf` (and its family of functions) are full of pitfalls for the new C programmer. For example, what happens in the user accidentally types an alpha-character instead of a "digit" at any of your `scanf ("%d", ...)` function calls? Try it.

When using `scanf`, if the input does not match the *conversion-specifier* used a *matching failure* occurs. When a *matching failure* occurs, reading from the input buffer stops, no further characters are extracted, leaving all characters as they existed at the time of the failure **unread** in the input buffer (`stdin` in your case), just waiting to bite you again on your next attempted read. Further, only *numeric* conversion specifiers and `"%s"` consume leading *whitespace*.

Meaning any other conversion specifier (or line-oriented input function for that matter) used for input with either fail to read anything (stopping when they encounter the `'\n'` generated by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> and left in `stdin`), or it will read `'\n'` as the user input. Neither is what you want.

How do you ensure that each input taken from the user will be what the user input? You clean up after yourself by emptying the input buffer after each input to insure there are no stray or additional characters left in `stdin` from the prior input attempt. (and this is also why new C programmers are encouraged to avoid `scanf` for user input and instead use a line-oriented input function like `fgets()` (with an adequate buffer size) or POSIX `getline` that will read and allocate as necessary to read any line. Both line-oriented functions *read and include* the `'\n'` in the buffers they fill eliminating the chance it remains in the input buffer unread.

If you choose to go forward with `scanf`, then at least manually empty the input buffer (`stdin`) with a simple function each time there is the possibility of characters remaining in `stdin` unread. A simple function will do it. Just read each character with `getchar()` until the `'\n'` or `EOF` is encountered, e.g.

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

**note:** if a function takes no parameters, then the proper declaration include `(void)` as the parameter list to make it explicit that no parameters are expected.

Now with a way to properly handle removing characters that remain in `stdin`, you are ready to look at your input functions.

If your intent with `getNumbers()`<sup>[1]</sup> and `getMoreNumbers()` was to simply read an integer from `stdin`, then simply use one function with a slightly more descriptive name to do the job, such as:

```
int readintstdin (int *value) {

    int rtn = 0;

    printf ("Enter digits: ");

    rtn = scanf ("%d", value);     /* read 1 integer */

    if (rtn == EOF)
        fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
    else if (rtn == 0)
        fputs (" readintstdin() error: invalid input.\n", stderr);

    empty_stdin();  /* remove all remaining chars from stdin */

    return rtn;
}
```

**Note:** when using `scanf`, you are responsible for handling three cases:

1. the user cancels input by manually generating `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd> on windows);
2. a *matching* or *input* failure; and
3. the good input case, where you then must validate whether the input received was within the expected range, etc..

With that in mind you can craft a function to read from `stdin` similar to:

```
int readintstdin (int *value) {

    int rtn = 0;

    printf ("Enter digits: ");

    rtn = scanf ("%d", value);     /* read 1 integer */

    if (rtn == EOF)
        fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
    else if (rtn == 0)
        fputs (" readintstdin() error: invalid input.\n", stderr);

    empty_stdin();  /* remove all remaining chars from stdin */

    return rtn;
}
```

**note two things, the **address of** value is passed as the parameter allowing the input to be stored at that memory address and available back in the calling function (`main()` here) and the **return** value for `scanf` is returned as the function return indicating success/failure of the read back in `main()`. You must always craft a function with an appropriate return type that will indicate success or failure of the function back in the calling function. Otherwise, it is no different that failing to check the return of `scanf` to begin with.

Your next goal appears to be reading all values from `"digits.txt"`. While it is up to you, the general approach is to open the `FILE* stream` back in the caller to validate a file is open for reading before passing that file stream as a parameter to the function. Otherwise, if the open fails, there is no need to call the function to begin with, e.g.:

```
int readfromfile (FILE *fp) {

    int value = 0, count = 0;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &value) == 1) {    /* while valid int read */
        printf ("%d ", value);
        count++;
    }

    putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up with newline */

    return count;   /* return value indicating number of values read */
}
```

Here to indicate success/failure of the read from the file, the number of values read from the file is returned. If the return is `0`, then no values were read from the file.

Next, your menu. You need to apply these same lessons to your menu. Meaning you need to handle all three cases for `scanf` and remove any characters that remain in `stdin` between each display of the menu. Putting those safeguards in place, you could do something like the following, e.g.

```
#define MAXC 1024
...
int main (void) {

    int input = 1,          /* initialize all variables */
        value = 0;
    char fname[MAXC] = "";  /* buffer to hold filename to read */
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    while (0 < input && input < 3) {
        int rtn = 0;    /* store scanf return */
        printf ("\nPlease select which method you'd like to access:\n"
                " 1) readintstdin()\n"
                " 2) readfromfile()\n"
                " (any other numeric input exits)\n\n"
                " choice: ");
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &input);
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* user generated manual EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn == 0) {    /* no integer input */
            fputs (" error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();  /* empty all chars from stdin */
            continue;       /* re-display menu, try again */
        }
        else    /* good integer input */
            empty_stdin();  /* empty all chars from stdin */
        ...
```

All that remains is handling `switch` on `input`. The first case calling `readintstdin` is trivial, just call `readintstdin` passing the *address of* `value` as its parameter and check the function return is non-zero before printing `value`, e.g.

```
        switch (input) {    /* switch on integer input */
            case 1:
                if (readintstdin (&value))  /* read from stdin */
                    printf ("value: %d\n", value);
                break;
```

The second case takes a bit more thought. You will take input from the user for the filename (thus the purpose for the variable `fname` at the beginning of `main()`). Here you simply prompt and read the filename (which may contain whitespace), validating the read and then passing the filename to `fopen` validating that the file is open for reading. Once you have confirmed that the file is open for reading, you can simply pass the open file stream to your function (checking the return of your function for success/failure) and then closing the file when done. That could be done similar to:

```
            case 2:
                printf ("\n enter filename: "); /* get filename to read */
                if (scanf ("%1023[^\n]", fname) != 1) {
                    fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                    empty_stdin();
                    break;
                }
                /* open/validate file open for reading */
                if ((fp = fopen (fname, "r")) == NULL) {
                    perror ("fopen-fname");
                    empty_stdin();
                    break;
                }
                if (!readfromfile (fp)) /* read/output integers */
                    fprintf (stderr, "error: no values read from '%s'\n",
                            fname);
                fclose (fp);        /* close file */
                break;
```

**note:** your `default:` case should advise the user that a value not within the accepted menu values was received, and then you can indicate the program was complete. (this is just a nit and you can handle it any way you like)

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXC 1024

void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int readintstdin (int *value) {

    int rtn = 0;

    printf ("Enter digits: ");

    rtn = scanf ("%d", value);     /* read 1 integer */

    if (rtn == EOF)
        fputs ("(user canceled input.)\n", stderr);
    else if (rtn == 0)
        fputs (" readintstdin() error: invalid input.\n", stderr);

    empty_stdin();  /* remove all remaining chars from stdin */

    return rtn;
}

int readfromfile (FILE *fp) {

    int value = 0, count = 0;

    while (fscanf (fp, "%d", &value) == 1) {    /* while valid int read */
        printf ("%d ", value);
        count++;
    }

    putchar ('\n'); /* tidy up with newline */

    return count;   /* return value indicating number of values read */
}  

int main (void) {

    int input = 1,      /* initialize all variables */
        value = 0;
    char fname[MAXC] = "";
    FILE *fp = NULL;

    while (0 < input && input < 3) {
        int rtn = 0;    /* store scanf return */
        printf ("\nPlease select which method you'd like to access:\n"
                " 1) readintstdin()\n"
                " 2) readfromfile()\n"
                " (any other numeric input exits)\n\n"
                " choice: ");
        rtn = scanf ("%d", &input);
        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* user generated manual EOF */
            fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
            break;
        }
        else if (rtn == 0) {    /* no integer input */
            fputs (" error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            empty_stdin();  /* empty all chars from stdin */
            continue;       /* re-display menu, try again */
        }
        else    /* good integer input */
            empty_stdin();  /* empty all chars from stdin */

        switch (input) {    /* switch on integer input */
            case 1:
                if (readintstdin (&value))  /* read from stdin */
                    printf ("value: %d\n", value);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf ("\n enter filename: "); /* get filename to read */
                if (scanf ("%1023[^\n]", fname) != 1) {
                    fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
                    empty_stdin();
                    break;
                }
                /* open/validate file open for reading */
                if ((fp = fopen (fname, "r")) == NULL) {
                    perror ("fopen-fname");
                    empty_stdin();
                    break;
                }
                if (!readfromfile (fp)) /* read/output integers */
                    fprintf (stderr, "error: no values read from '%s'\n",
                            fname);
                fclose (fp);        /* close file */
                break;
            default:    /* handle invalid input */
                fputs ("Selection not menu entry.\n", stderr);
                break;
        }  
    }
    printf ("Program complete\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**note:** unless you are using a function or constant provided by `stdlib.h`, there is no reason to include the header. It doesn't hurt, it just reveals a misunderstanding of the required header files.

**Example Use/Output**

Now go exercise your program and intentionally try and break your input routine by entering improper/invalid input at each of your prompts. If something breaks, go fix it. I didn't try every corner case, but understanding how your input functions work, lets you protect against most corner cases to begin with. Look at the first integer input `"four-hundred twenty-one"`, does the program break? No. Look at the invalid filename `"somefile.ext"`, does the program break? No. Do that for each of your inputs.

```
$ ./bin/menureadfilestdin

Please select which method you'd like to access:
 1) readintstdin()
 2) readfromfile()
 (any other numeric input exits)

 choice: 1
Enter digits: four-hundred twenty-one
 readintstdin() error: invalid input.

Please select which method you'd like to access:
 1) readintstdin()
 2) readfromfile()
 (any other numeric input exits)

 choice: 1
Enter digits: 421
value: 421

Please select which method you'd like to access:
 1) readintstdin()
 2) readfromfile()
 (any other numeric input exits)

 choice: 2

 enter filename: somefile.ext
fopen-fname: No such file or directory

Please select which method you'd like to access:
 1) readintstdin()
 2) readfromfile()
 (any other numeric input exits)

 choice: 2

 enter filename: dat/digits.txt
1 10 299 1 200 15 3 150 13 2 150

Please select which method you'd like to access:
 1) readintstdin()
 2) readfromfile()
 (any other numeric input exits)

 choice: 1
Enter digits: 422
value: 422

Please select which method you'd like to access:
 1) readintstdin()
 2) readfromfile()
 (any other numeric input exits)

 choice: (user canceled input)
Program complete
```

Hopefully this addressed most of your problems and helps you avoid *"really getting stressed out over WHAT I FEEL is a simple problem."* It is, but C requires a depth of understanding well beyond *"I'll try this, if it doesn't work, I'll change something, recompile and try again..."* You have control over the entire machine and are responsible for handling each byte of your input buffer and ensuring adequate storage for each byte your program handles. There are no training-wheels on C. That is where it derives its blazing speed. But, "with great power comes great responsibility".

**footnotes:**

**1.** While not an error, C generally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. It is a matter of style -- so it is completely up to you, but failing to follow it can lead to the wrong first impression in some circles.

Comment: Sure. Everybody needs a hand up every now and then. We all started with the same questions. C isn't something you learn in a month, or a year, etc... It's more a journey than something you do in a semester or two. The key to learning C is simply to *slow down*. Read the man page for each function you use, and just slowly absorb the details -- there is a lot to learn. But there is no better language to learn. C will make you a better programmer regardless what you end up writing in. Anyone can learn a language -- few learn to program. C is about programming.