# storing database in a dynamic location and accessing it with my deployed application

Tags: c++, database, exe

I am using Installshield to deploy my application which is developed in vc++,MS-Access DB.Here I have to store the database dynamic location  when the time of installation. If the db file already exist then it only gets the path.
After that I need to create a property file that store the path of db.and from the property file data i need to access my db.How to do this? Can any one help me in this?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. From your question I'm having trouble understanding what you need help with; could you be a little more specific? If you need a way to create a property file in C++ a similar question has been asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874052/properties-file-library-for-c-or-c . Do you also need advice on how to access the database once you have the path?

Comment: hi thank you for ur reply. actually i am using installshield to create setup file.on this setup file i have an option to change the database folder. now I have to store the database folder file location which is changed by the time of installation to a property file from which my application getting db location.